# Calling a API twice on same page fails second time in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fetch-api

Code working fine in codepen but while trying to run in WordPress page using shortcode it's not running. What could be the reason. All of the remaining content below this code are also not showing. Especially while trying to run js in page nothing showing.

```
  <script>
    // Fetch the exchange rates from the API
    fetch(`https://api.fastforex.io/fetch-multi?from=AED&to=USD,EUR,GBP,INR,AUD,CAD,SGD,CHF,MYR,JPY&api_key=xxxxx-xxx-xxx`)// API key on purpose
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Update the exchange rates in the table
        document.getElementById("eur").innerHTML = data.results.EUR;
document.getElementById("gbp").innerHTML = data.results.GBP;
document.getElementById("chf").innerHTML = data.results.CHF;
document.getElementById("eur").innerHTML = data.results.EUR;
document.getElementById("gbp").innerHTML = data.results.GBP;
document.getElementById("chf").innerHTML = data.results.CHF;
document.getElementById("usd").innerHTML = data.results.USD;
document.getElementById("inr").innerHTML = data.results.INR;
document.getElementById("aud").innerHTML = data.results.AUD;
document.getElementById("cad").innerHTML = data.results.CAD;
document.getElementById("sgd").innerHTML = data.results.SGD;
document.getElementById("myr").innerHTML = data.results.MYR;
document.getElementById("jpy").innerHTML = data.results.JPY;

      });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What does your shortcode function look like? can you post it?

Comment: check for unclosed functions.

Comment: what remaining content? you're closing the <body>.. Where are the divs with their respective id's ?